# How can I alter my margin-left-increase function to disable if margin-left = 0px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code I have thus far. The code is actually working fine so here's to hoping it's a tiny tweak someone can assist me with?

So my width on the UL is 2000px, with the overflow hidden. It is for the user to scroll through a list of thumbnails to choose from to display in a div above.

Still, I would like to see it done in the interest of curiosity

HTML:

```
<img class="thumbSliderLeft" src="Images/left.png" />
<div class="thumbContainer">


<ul class="galleryThumbs">
<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/sam.jpg" /></li>

<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/cat.jpg" /></li>

<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/horse.jpg" /></li>

<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/mags.jpg" /></li>

<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/tree.jpg" /></li>

<li class="gallery"><img class="thumb" src="Images/thumbs/soup.jpg" /></li>

</ul>



</div>
```

CSS

```
div.thumbContainer {
            width: 800px;
            height: 270px;
            position: relative;
            top: -50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.galleryThumbs {
    width: 2000px;
}

ul.galleryThumbs li.gallery {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 5px;}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(function () {

    var marginLeft = $("ul.galleryThumbs").css("margin-left");

    var indentLeft = $("img.thumbSliderLeft").click(function () {
        $("ul.galleryThumbs").animate({
            "margin-left": "+=250px"
        }, 500, 'linear');

        if (marginLeft === 0) {
            indentLeft.off()
        };

    });
});
```

Comment: "The code is actually working fine" - so what are you asking?

Comment: What does `0` represent at `marginLeft === 0` ? Can include `html` , `css` at Question ?

Comment: I meant it is completing the run fine - as in, there are no errors in it.

Comment: move the `var marginLeft` statement inside the `.click` function?????

Comment: @greatbow Given `css` , `js` at updated Question ,  not certain how `marginLeft` could have value `0` ?

Comment: Got it from the console in Firefox. Disappointed it doesn't work but I guess it will remain unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, try using `.off(event)` ; note that `.animate()` would set `margin-left` to `String` ending in `"px"` , not `Number` `0` .

Not clear at Question what `0` expected to represent at `marginLeft === 0` ?

```
$(function () {

        var marginLeft = $("ul.galleryThumbs").css("margin-left");

        $("img.thumbSliderLeft").on("click", function () {
            $("ul.galleryThumbs").animate({
                "margin-left": "+=250px"
            }, 500, 'linear');

            if (marginLeft === 0) { 
                $(this).off("click")
            };

        });
    });
```

Comment: What the animation runs, it increments at 250px, so margin-left becomes -250px, - 500px. I only want it to work when the margin-left property is over 250px (I have a function that increases the position 250px).

Comment: _"it increments at 250px, so margin-left becomes -250px, - 500px."_ Appear `margin-left` increments to `250px` , `500px` ? Does `js` at post return expected results ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: It doesn't I'm afraid. That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @greatbow _"It doesn't I'm afraid. "_ If possible , can include `html` , `css`  at Question ?

Comment: What value should `marginLeft`  have to call `.off()` ?  `"0px"` ?

Comment: Yes. So I am told in other answers - that it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not picking up `=== 0` is that you're comparing a string to an int.

As well as that, when you get the css using jquery you'll get a `px` after the value. you can fix this by adding the following:

```
if (parseInt(marginLeft.replace('px','')) === 0){
 //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the check for margin-left to the top of the handler and check for a 0 at the start of the string that css() returns:

```
    if ($("ul.galleryThumbs").css("margin-left")[0] === '0') {
        indentLeft.off()
    }
    $("ul.galleryThumbs").animate({
        "margin-left": "+=250px"
    }, 500, 'linear');
```